# How can I find the integral $\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2/4+z^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

More specifically my integral is

$$\frac{4z\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2/4+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

The answer I'm looking for looks something like this:
$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{8\lambda a z}{\sqrt{2a^2+4z^2}(z^2+a^2/4)}$

I really don't see any way to do this.

Comment: This problem comes from the context of electromagnetism. By the way I've noticed there is a trick in solving this problem without having to consider an antiderivative. I have my qualms about deleting this question, but maybe finding the antiderivative is interesting.

Comment: Never mind, at the end of the day you do have to consider a hairy antridervative :(. I've seen sources just quote "Wolfram says this integral is..."

Comment: And by the way, it come from considering the electric field above the center of a square sheet with side lengths $a$.

Comment: Behold: the [edit] button. For adding information to your post which really doesn't belong in the comments.

Comment: I know the edit button.  I didn't add it as part of the question since I was concerned about finding the antiderivative and not with solving the physics problem. Many physics problem avoid complex mathematics by "tricks" and I wasn't interested in that for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hairy. Working temporarily with a single constant $b$ you find an anti-derivative $F(x,b)$
$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+b)^{3/2}} = F(x,b)=\frac{x}{b\sqrt{x^2+b}}$$ 
Now substitute $b$ with your constants
$$F\left(x,\frac{a^2}{4}+z^2\right)=
\frac{x}{(a^2/4+z^2)\sqrt{x^2+a^2/2+z^2}}$$
$$F\left(\pm\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a^2}{4}+z^2\right)
=\pm\frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{(a^2/4+z^2)\sqrt{a^2/2+z^2}}
$$ 
and get for your integral
$$
\frac{4z\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2/4+z^2)^{3/2}}
=\frac{4z\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon}\frac{a}{(a^2/4+z^2)\sqrt{a^2/2+z^2}}
=\frac{4z\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon}\frac{2a}{(a^2/4+z^2)\sqrt{2a^2+4z^2}}
$$

Comment: Yes but how did you find that antiderivative?